# Start SVG animation empty

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I'm relativly new in this topic and I just started experimenting with SVG animations.

I made a cloud loader, and so far its looks quite good, I just want to make it start after a short time, right now it starts immediately.

Here is my CodePen snipped: https://codepen.io/PascalRoh/pen/xxbVaXR

```
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
   animation: dash2 5.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.path3 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
   animation: dash3 5.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes dash2 {
  0% {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 0, 7900;
  }
  58% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    stroke-dasharray: 1200, 600;
  }
   100% {
  stroke-dashoffset: -400px;
  stroke-dasharray: 270, 2300;
  }
}

@keyframes dash3 {
  0% {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 0, 2400;
  }
   8% {
  stroke-dashoffset: 20;
  stroke-dasharray: 0, 2400;
  }
  78% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    stroke-dasharray: 1200, 600;
  }
   100% {
  stroke-dashoffset: -400px;
  stroke-dasharray: 270, 2300;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `animation-delay: 3s`

Comment: In CSS you can use `animation-delay`